# How can I revert all my files back to one of an earlier commits from another branch?

Tags: git

For example, I have a commit `aaaa` in Branch1. The latest commit in Branch1 is `bbbb`. I am currently in Branch2 and I want to discard all my commits in Branch2 and revert all files back to their versions in Branch1 commit `aaaa`.

The files in Branch 1 remain as they are. So the end result would have 2 similar copies of files in Branch1 and Branch2.

How can I do this in git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Branch2` run:

```
git reset --hard aaaa
```

Comment: Will this automatically remove any additional files in Branch2 that `aaaa` don't have?

Comment: @Carven - Yes. This will basically make `Branch2` point to the commit `aaaa`